# Is there any limit that in_array function can fail?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contain all English words that start with a specific character and I want to find if a word I supply exist in that array

When I use in_array function with a minimum data it works, but it failed when the data grows base on dictionary table in my database

```
// It works 

$array =  array('word01','word02');

if(in_array('word001', $array)){

    echo "found";
}else{

    echo "not found";
}

// It Not works

$array = array('word01','word02','word03..');

if(in_array('word001',$array) == true){

  echo "found";

}else{

  echo "not found";

}
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Array size is unlimited in PHP (well, the only thing that can "break" it is the memory limit). So there is no reason `in_array` should fail even with huge ones.

Comment: In both cases you see `not found` as `word001` is not present in your array.

Comment: Can you show the code fragment that fills the array from your database?

Comment: php execution time limit reached ?

Comment: If you have the words in a database table, why not query for it instead?